Spring MVC canot get the EL values
this  is my empInfo.jsp
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" isELIgnored="false"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>empInfo.jsp</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="pages/addEmp.jsp">添加</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>eno_id </td>
                <td>员工姓名</td>
                ...
                <c:out value="${emp_info}" />
                <td>操作</td>
            </tr>
        <%-- Debugging to check if emp_info is populated --%>
        <cut value="${emp_info}" />
        <c:forEach items="${emp_info}" var="emp">
            <tr>
                <td>${emp.eno}</td>
                ...
                <td>${emp.dno}</td>
                <td><a href="/emps/delEmpByeno?eno=${emp.eno}">删除</a>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
        </table>
    </div>

</body>
</html>

this is my controller:
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/emps")
public class EmpController extends BasicController{

    @Autowired
    private EmpSerive empSerive;
    @GetMapping("/selectAll")
    public String getAllEmp(Model model){
        List<Employee> employeeList = empSerive.selectAllEmp();
        model.addAttribute("emp_info",employeeList);
        return "empInfo";
    }

when i debug the empInfo.jsp, the Idea says : cannot find the local variables. like the picture.
[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/eAkg0Z6v.png)
what should I do to show the data to jsp which datas from database?enter image description here
